# How are greengrocers referred to in American English?

Tags: american-english

How are greengrocers referred to in American English, assuming that they exist in the US?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greengrocer) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greengrocer) say that it's primarily a term in British and Australian English but don't give a definitive explanation of what Americans use, and Japanese for Busy People II page 129 defines "八百屋" as "fruit and vegetable dealer", which seems rather clumsy.

I'm primarily interested in the shop, rather than the person.

Comment: [Must ... resist ... temptation ... to ... incorrectly ... spell ... "greengrocers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Superfluous_apostrophes_.28.22greengrocers.27_apostrophes.22.29)

Comment: grocery stores and farmers markets in the states.

Comment: We'd call it a "fruit store" or maybe a "fruit and vegetable store." They are probably more common in the U.K., but they definitely exist in the U.S. – they're quite common in New York City. And instead of "greengrocer" or "fruit and vegetable dealer," we'd probably say something like "the guy that owns (or runs) the fruit store."

Comment: The word "produce" is often used...produce dealer, produce stand,  produce market.......

Comment: Yep, "produce" is probably the most common adjective applied to such shops.  Outside of hoity-toity areas it would be unusual to find a shop devoted solely to produce, however (except farmers' markets in the growing season), and folks generally assume that a "grocery" or "food market" includes produce, at least to a modest degree.  (Heck, gas stations include produce anymore.)

Comment: (I'll add that the noun/adjective is "PROduce", with a fairly strong accent on the first syllable, unlike the verb.)

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to find such a place in the US, or wondering how to translate the term so it will be clearly understood, or something else? I think the exact term you want might vary depending on how/why you want to use it.

Comment: @J.Taylor If you changed your comment to an answer I would upvote it, even as is.

Comment: @Keeta  I don't think I can write a definitive answer. Produce is most common in my experience, but there are other terms used in the United States , including greengrocer

Comment: In California, we call it a "fruit stand", especially if it's located in a rural area. In cities, it's pretty rare to find a grocery that sells fruits and vegetables, but doesn't also sell meats, dairy, canned goods, etc.

Comment: produce dealer? Nope, I have never ever seen that. In NY city, the Koreans have a lot of fruit and vege but I wouldn't call those fruit and vege stores, at least not in the Theatre District where I lived.

Comment: Sadly, gone are the days when every town had its own greengrocer shop. A few still remain, but generally the supermarkets have cornered the market in fruit and veg. Some convenience stores, though, sell a limited range of items, and farm shops in rural areas sell fruit and veg as well as an assortment of other items like eggs, conserves, plants and flowers etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, so down the road from where I live in the NE (of the US), there is a fruit-and-vegetable market. Not a dealer, for pity's sake. :) And yes, fruit and vegetables are also called produce, tonic accent on the pro.

Nowadays, there are smaller super markets that have begun to re-specialize in high quality, locally or regionally produced fruit and vegetables, but even so, these establishments  typically sell other things as well. Essentially though, the 19th century seller of only fruit and vegetables i.e. a greengrocer as found in a town along a main street went by the wayside or stayed there. Please read on.

**Roadside fruit-and-vegetable stands** are everywhere on secondary roads that go by farms, and this is the case historically as well. And some farms, do have large facilities selling fruit and vegetables and these are called **farmers' markets.** Typically, a wooden building filled with stands of fruits and vegetables. Also, cities and towns are holding farmers' markets on the weekends or in the summer. My town has one in a  park's parking lot that runs from June through early September. Besides fruit and vegetables, there are also locally produced cheeses, jams and some pottery.

Here is a well-done historical document on this topic from the USDA: [farmers' markets](https://www.nal.usda.gov/exhibits/ipd/localfoods/exhibits/show/stands-and-markets/farmers-markets) The first part of the document has great pictures of roadside farm stands that, in fact, look pretty much like the roadside stands of today.

The document also says this about farmers' markets:

> Throughout the United States, the number of farmers markets continues
>   to rise, their popularity spurred by consumers’ growing demand for
>   locally produced food. More than 4,900 farmers markets operate
>   nationwide today—a jump from fewer than 1,800 only 15 years ago. In
>   addition to providing easier access to fresh food, studies show
>   establishing a farmers market can revitalize a neighborhood, enhance
>   social interaction, improve the local economy, and provide a
>   supplemental source of farm income for many growers.

in turn, that document quotes this book:

Direct Farm Marketing as a Rural Development Tool (1997). Gale, Fred Rural Development Perspectives, 12(2), pp. 19-25

> “Farmers’ markets are, of course, the oldest and most common type of
>   direct selling. A 1993 directory of farmers’ markets published by the
>   USDA listed 1,755 operating markets. The total number of farmers’
>   markets may actually be much larger, since this was not an exhaustive
>   list and probably excluded many smaller markets. Marketing specialists
>   at USDA and land-grant colleges believe that the number of **farmers’
>   markets** is growing, although there are no historical statistics for
>   comparison. **Markets vary widely. Some are year-round, others are
>   seasonal; some are held in permanent indoor facilities, others are
>   held in parking lots.**” p. 20

In the US, small-scale butcher shops and greengrocers were replaced by large supermarkets at some point around the mid-twentieth century. So, it is not that the term is necessarily British, it's that main street shops called greengrocers went the way of dry goods' stores and local emporia. [large supermarkets](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2015/11/cities-economic-fates-diverge/417372/)

Comment: +1 TL;DR for the OP: the store that a greengrocer runs is just very uncommon in the US (it appears in some very urban areas like NYC or downtown Boston). Fruits and vegetables are gotten at a bigger grocery store. So there is no special occupation in the US of being a greengrocer.

Comment: Please read my answer more carefully.  Greengrocer  stores were replaced by supermarkets. Anyway, we would say produce seller or fruit-and-vegetable seller today.

Comment: “Not a dealer, for pity's sake. :)“ - does “dealer” have negative connotations?

Comment: It's just off. Though, I have to say you will find "coke dealers" in old SIC codes, I believe. An antique dealer, but not a fruit and vegetable dealer.

Comment: @Andrew: *dealer* (except of illegal drugs) are generally wholesale sellers, not retail sellers. You can say *rare book dealer* or *antique dealer* because they spend a lot of time scouting for the goods they sell, but you wouldn't say *fruit and vegetable dealer*, or *book dealer* for somebody who runs an ordinary bookstore.

Comment: Lengthy  ... I do not see an answer to the question. I have never heard greengrocer used and are there but a few fruit/veg bodegas in dense dense urban areas

Comment: @lbf: I really don't think *bodega* is used anywhere which doesn't have a large Latino population.

Comment: @ibf  fruit and vegetable growers or producers or farmers; fruit and vegetable sellers; fruit and vegetable distributors; fruit and vegetable retailers and wholesalers; but not dealers. Dealers are wholesalers but the term is not generally used for fruit and vegetables or produce. And bodegas are basically convenience stores that sell a lot more junk food and canned goods than fruits and vegetables, at least for the ones in and around NYC, for instance.

Comment: @PeterShor which is why they are prevalent in America's largest urban cities: bodega, fruitstand , fruit veg and beverage cart, but no 'greengrocers'.

Comment: @ibf You still do not get it. ***Historically, there were green grocers, but they all disappeared when super markets came on the scene***. Just like butcher shops or bakeries for bread. The latter have made a huge comeback in the last 20 years. For much of the second half of the 20th century, bakeries basically only sold cakes and pastries and a very limited selection of breads, mostly dinner rolls and white loaf bread.

Comment: Bodegas are  basically a convenience store with a few boxes of things like plantains or yucca, which, until more recently, the large supermarkets did not carry.

Comment: @Lambie: they didn't all disappear. The butchers (amazingly good!) that we used when we lived in suburban New Jersey are still around,  and have been around for at least 65 years, and probably much longer.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, the odd butcher shop is still to be found here and there. But they are not along every Main Street, as it were.  Some of the Main Street stores and shops are making come backs, others not. Have you read: Huck and Tom Don't Live Here Anymore? So saaad. Anyway, that's about the disappearance of the small town rather than main street per se.

Comment: While I agree with the answer overall, I would clarify that *farmers market* sometimes refers to a [a facility](http://easternmarket-dc.org/) ("a wooden building…") and sometimes to [an event](http://www.capitalharvestdc.com/) ("cities and towns are holding farmers' markets"); otherwise, it sounds like your town is erecting a wooden building in that parking lot every week, which seems unlikely. In my idiolect (and how I see the term used in the Washington, D.C. area) *farmers markets* are recurring events held in urbanized areas, *farm markets* are located on farms.

Comment: @choster Yes, I did not use the word event.  But I did say: Also, cities and towns ***are holding*** farmers' markets ***on the weekends or in the summer.*** That  implies an event.  So it doesn't sound like "my town is erecting a wooden building in that parking lot every week".